# JQGrid Client Side Sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

This is a question that I know has been asked here and several other places on the internet. I have tried all of the solutions I could find on the StackOverflow site with the same result, nothing solved my problem.

I want to load the data from the database once, and then do all of the sorting operations on the client. The loadonce property sounds like it is supposed to handle this, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I've also tried setting the datatype to local in various event handlers with no success.

Here is the code I am using to instantiate the grid.

```
        $('#people_SelectedContacts').jqGrid({
        ajaxGridOptions:{
            type: "POST"
        },
        datatype: function(data){
            $.ajax(klg.getAppRoot()+"AJAX/GetMatterProfileContacts",{
                            data: JSON.stringify({
                MatterProfileID: $('#MatterProfileID').val()
            }),
            success: function(data){
                var contacts = data.ReturnValues;
                var mygrid = $("#people_SelectedContacts")[0];
                mygrid.addJSONData(contacts);
            },
            complete: function(){
                $("#people_SelectedContacts").setGridParam({datatype:'local'});
            }});
        },
        loadonce: true,
        colNames:['lecID','lrlID','mjID','Role','Name','Company/Court', 'Business Phone', 'Email', 'Docket #'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'LegalEntityContactID', hidden:true},
            {name:'LegalRoleLookupID', hidden:true},
            {name:'MatterJurisdictionID', hidden:true},
            {name:'LegalRoleLookupName', index:'legalrole'},
            {name:'FullName',index:'name'},
            {name:'Company',index:'company'},
            {name:'BusinessPhone',index:'bussphone'},
            {name:'Email',index:'email'},
            {name:'DocketNumber',index:'email'}
        ],
        sortable: true,
        jsonReader: {
            root:'MatterProfileContacts',
            repeatitems: false,
            id:"MatterProfileContactID"
        }
    });
```

The data loads into the grid correctly, but as I said, the sorting commands all go and hit the server again. Can anyone point my in the right direction? The only reason I switched from a standard HTML table to the JQGrid is for sorting and grouping. If I can't get client-side sorting to work, it's useless.

Thank you Stack Overflow community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the grid to use datatype: 'json' as you suggested by Oleg. I still had the sorting problem but I realized that it was because of the `index` values I was using in the column model. The `index` values of the column model has to match the property names of the JSON objects being returned from the server.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of your problem is that you use `datatype` as function which is not needed in 99,9% of cases. The problem is that setting `datatype: 'local'` is not the only thing which jqGrid do in case of `loadonce: true`. The most important thing is that the `data` and `_index` parameters will be filled with the data returned from the server. The internal parameters hold the data and will be used during local sorting and paging. You current implementation don't fill `data` and `_index`, so `loadonce: true` can't work.

Instead of usage `datatype` as function you can use

```
datatype: 'json',
serializeGridData: function (data) { return JSON.stringify(data); },
postData: { MatterProfileID: function () { return $('#MatterProfileID').val(); } }
```

You should additionally modify `jsonReader` to include `ReturnValues` in the `root`. I think after the changes you will be able to use `loadonce: true`. Probably there are some other small things which you need to do additionally, but the most important that you should use any standard `datatype` instead of `datatype` as function.

Comment: While this did not directly answer my question, it did lead me in the right direction. I changed the grid to use datatype: 'json' as you suggested. I still had the sorting problem but I realized that it was because of the index values I was using. I didn't realize it had to match the data property of the JSON array.

Comment: @Zero21xxx: Yes, in case of server side data `index` can be different as the `name` property. In case of local data or in case of `loadonce: true` the `index` should be the same as `name`. I could not describe all problems which you need to solve. For example it could be important for you to include `sorttype` for all columns which has other sorting type as 'text' ('integer' or 'date' for example). In any way if you use now `datatype: 'json'` - you are on the correct way.